# What are the registration requirements when visiting Russia?

Tags: visas, legal, russia, saint-petersburg, registration

I'm visiting Russia, and I've read that I need to register my visa after arrival.

Some hotels do this for you, but I'm staying in a rental apartment. What exactly do I need to do? Where should I go?

I'm staying in Saint Petersburg.

What will happen if I don't register?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/442/when-travelling-overland-in-russia-i-hear-you-must-register-with-the-police-in-e

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The authoritative answer is at [Way to Russia](http://www.waytorussia.net/RussianVisa/Registration.html), but I'll summarize for posterity.

- Whoever you're staying with, be it hotel or apartment, is supposed to take care of registering you.
- They can take care of the registration at any police station or post office, you do not need to be present.
- When it's done, they'll get a piece of paper for you that confirms registration, and all is good.

If you do not register, *and* you're stopped by police, *and* it's been over seven working days since you arrived in Russia, you'll be fined (€50-100).  In theory, you can even be deported and blacklisted for returning for 5 years, but this is very unlikely.

In your case, I'd get in touch with whoever is renting you the apartment and ensure they sort it out, the magic word is *propiska* (registration).  It's in their best interest to do so as well, since they can also get fined even more heavily for having unregistered foreigners staying with them.

Comment: Actually *propiska* means something like 'constant registration' which has different legal meaning than registration (just *registratsiya*). Natives have *propiska* for place where they constantly live in, it gives them legally approved rights to do so. So for rented apartment you just need *registratsiya*.

Comment: Interesting -- in Finnish *proopuska* (obviously borrowed from the Russian) means any official government authorization to do something, particularly when it's a little silly (like, say, the "right" to live somewhere!).

Comment: "_and_ it's been over a week since you arrived in Russia" - shouldn't this be "since you arrived in the city you're staying"? Because for every city you need a new registration.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is staying only in St. Petersburg.